# pymongo MongoClient can not work in multiprocess?

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo

I am using `pymongo 3.2`, I want to use it in multiporcess:

```
client = MongoClient(JD_SEARCH_MONGO_URI, connect=False)
db = client.jd_search

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for jd in db['sample_data'].find():
        jdId = jd["jdId"]
        for cv in db["sample_data"].find():
            itemId = cv["itemId"]
            executor.submit(intersect_compute, jdId, itemId)
            #  print "done {} => {}".format(jdId, itemId)
```

but I get error:

```
UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with connect=False, or create client after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing>
```

according to the documentation, I have set `connect` to `False` as you can see

Comment: what platform are you using? The documentation says `connect` needs to be set to `False` only if your platform is `APPLE`,`FreeBSD`,`VMS`,`OPENBSD` or `NetBSD`.
According to the information [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1016), If in your parent process you collect some data from MongoDB, then close the connection.
Then, in the child processes when a new connection is opened to get something else, it triggers the warning.

Comment: I develop in APPLE, I have a remote machine `ubuntu 14`

Comment: So, it would be for Ubuntu. Anyways, it is just a warning and not an error. Pymongo issues the warning if there is a chance of a deadlock.

Comment: Can you also show the code for `intersect_compute()`? My guess would be that the function uses either `client` or `db` global variable. Try to create and use a new client inside `intersect_compute()`.

Answer (score 3):

You did exactly like in the documentation (URL in exception), but in the section `Never do this`.
p.s. I updated your code sample at the end of the comment.

#### Create connection to database inside each process:

```
# Each process creates its own instance of MongoClient.
def func():
    db = pymongo.MongoClient().mydb
    # Do something with db.

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
proc.start()
```

#### Never do this:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()

# Each child process attempts to copy a global MongoClient
# created in the parent process. Never do this.
def func():
  db = client.mydb
  # Do something with db.

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
proc.start()
```

What you need to change is to move database connection initialization to a fork of each process. As each of them will have own independent connection.

#### Your sample updated:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    client = MongoClient(JD_SEARCH_MONGO_URI, connect=False)
    db = client.jd_search

    for jd in db['sample_data'].find():
        jdId = jd["jdId"]
        for cv in db["sample_data"].find():
            itemId = cv["itemId"]
            executor.submit(intersect_compute, jdId, itemId)
            #  print "done {} => {}".format(jdId, itemId)
```